# angular material mat-checkbox binding problem

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am using angular material for checkbox.

in component.ts

```
dataList: any[] = [
    { name: 'EmployeeName', flag: true, 'label': 'Employee Name'},
    { name: 'EmployeeDepartment', flag: false, 'label': 'Employee Department'},
    { name: 'EmployeeExperience', flag: false, , 'label': 'Employee Experience'}
]; // will have 30+ element in array
```

html (this opens as modal)

```
<div *ngFor="let data of dataList">
 <section>
  <mat-checkbox [checked]="data.flag" (change)="onChange($event, data)">{{data.label}}</mat-checkbox>
 </section>
</div>
<div>
  <button (click)="onClose()">
    Close
  </button>
  <button(click)="onApply()">Apply</button>
</div>
```

some of the checkbox will be pre-checked, if checked than behind modal there we will be filter dropdown for checked object.

problem is if I check the object(eg- Employee Department), than behind the modal that object(Employee Department) will be added instantly and the change in UI will be visible. what I want is add that filter object (user can select multiple object at a time) only after clicking apply button and changes in UI should be visible. if I click on close that nothing should be added.

html for behind modal page

```
//<ngx-select-dropdown> whole config is not listed
<div class="grid-container">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let data  of dataList">
      <div class="grid-item" *ngIf="data.flag">
        <div>
          <p>{{data.name }}</p>
        </div>
        <ngx-select-dropdown [config]="config">
        </ngx-select-dropdown>
      </div>
    </ng-container>
 </div>
```

I tried keeping checkbox values in another object and set value only on click of apply but the problem persisted. what should I do in **onChange($event, data)** and **onApply()** so that I can achieve the behavior I want.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You could simply save the checkbox values in another object and once the user hits the apply button then have your function for example
`onApply()` that will assign the new values from the checkbox to your data